# Sending an email with PasswordRecovery when there are multiple accounts

Tags: c#, asp.net-membership, password-recovery

I'm using the PasswordRecovery Control and can't send more then one email when there are multiple accounts with the same email. I get a MembershipUserCollection with Membership.FindUsersByEmail. I then loop through it in a foreach.  My problem is if there is more then one user it only sends the last email.  How can I get it to send an email for each account as it loops through? The delagate is called the correct number of times.  Also, I know they are all going to the same email, but would like there to be one sent for each account.

Code Snip:

```
protected void PasswordRecovery1_SendingMail(object sender, MailMessageEventArgs e)
{

}

bool IsValidEmail(string strIn)
{
    // Return true if strIn is in valid e-mail format.
    return Regex.IsMatch(strIn, @"^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$");
}


protected void PasswordRecovery1_VerifyingUser(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (IsValidEmail(PasswordRecovery1.UserName))
    {
        // string uName = Membership.GetUserNameByEmail(PasswordRecovery1.UserName) ?? PasswordRecovery1.UserName;
        MembershipUserCollection users = Membership.FindUsersByEmail(PasswordRecovery1.UserName);
        if (users.Count < 1)
        {
            PasswordRecovery1.UserName = " ";
            PasswordRecovery1.UserNameFailureText = "That user is not available"; }
        else
        {
            foreach (MembershipUser user in users)
            {

                PasswordRecovery1.UserName = user.UserName;
                PasswordRecovery1.SendingMail += PasswordRecovery1_SendingMail;
                PasswordRecovery1.SuccessTemplateContainer.Visible = true;

            }

        }
    }
    else
    { 
        PasswordRecovery1.UserName = " ";
        PasswordRecovery1.UserNameFailureText ="Please enter a valid e-mail";           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out ... the way I was originally doing it would not work, so I went semi-custom. I added an event handler on the submit button and edited the code as shown below. As you can see, I simply looped thorough the collection.  Not the best I'm sure, but it works and is easy to understand.

The body of the email is created in a txt file with html formatting.  Using the **mailDefinition** class allows me to have replacement strings, which simplifies the emails body creation.

It sends a separate email for each account to the same email.  I could have put them all into a single email, but this is what they wanted ...

```
protected void PasswordRecovery1_SendingMail(object sender, MailMessageEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}

bool IsValidEmail(string strIn)
{
    // Return true if strIn is a valid e-mail
    return Regex.IsMatch(strIn, @"^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$");
}

protected void SubmitLinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsValidEmail(PasswordRecovery1.UserName))
    {
        // Get user collection by shared email
        MembershipUserCollection users = Membership.FindUsersByEmail(PasswordRecovery1.UserName);
        if (users.Count < 1)
        {
            PasswordRecovery1.UserName = " ";
            PasswordRecovery1.UserNameFailureText = "That user is not available";
        }
        else
        {
            // Loop and email each user in collection
            foreach (MembershipUser user in users)
            {
                MembershipUser ur = Membership.GetUser(user.UserName);

                DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

                // Using MailDefinition instead of MailMessage so we can substitue strings
                MailDefinition md = new MailDefinition();

                // list of strings in password.txt file to be replace
                ListDictionary replacements = new ListDictionary();
                replacements.Add("<%UserName%>", ur.UserName);
                replacements.Add("<%Password%>", ur.GetPassword());

                // Text file that is in html format
                md.BodyFileName = "absolute path to password.txt";
                md.IsBodyHtml = true;
                md.Priority = MailPriority.High;
                md.Subject = "Email Subject Line - " + now.ToString("MM/dd - h:mm tt");
                md.From = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FromEmailAddress"];

                // Add MailDefinition to the MailMessage
                MailMessage mailMessage = md.CreateMailMessage(ur.Email, replacements, this);
                mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FromEmailAddress"], "Friendly Name");
                SmtpClient m = new SmtpClient();
                m.Host = "127.0.0.1";
                m.Send(mailMessage);

                PasswordRecovery1.UserName = user.UserName;

                PasswordRecovery1.SendingMail += PasswordRecovery1_SendingMail;
            }

        }
    }
    else
    {
        PasswordRecovery1.UserName = " ";
        PasswordRecovery1.UserNameFailureText = "Please enter a valid e-mail";
    }
}
```